# Escape doesn't work in jade templates

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

I have used jade in a express project and in this case I get the data from a API, what I get is a **html response** and I am avoiding the tags like this:

```
div.scroll!= event.description
```

I have it tried as well:

```
div.scroll !{event.description}
```

That's what jade documentation says, but it doesn't work in my case.

Here is the code (line 32) in [github](https://github.com/MallorcaJS/mallorcajs.com/blob/master/app/views/index.jade).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you trying to display the response as HTML, or to escape the HTML so it renders as text?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work in my case?" What is an example value of `event.description`, what is the markup that's currently being generated with that for `div.scroll`, and what would you like the markup to be?

Comment: @xShirase trying to display the html response.
Jonathan --> The response is a json with description key and html value eg: <a href="#">response</a> and some text...
div.scroll= event.description or div.scroll #{event.description} doesn't escape anything in jade

Comment: it does! both works for me